# a lesson concerning/about

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

1. The professor *teaches a lesson concerning* the nature of knowledge.
2. The professor *teaches a lesson about* the nature of knowledge.

Is option (1) more formal than option (2)? It seems to me that ***to teach a lesson concerning something*** is a more formal expression than ***to teach a lesson about something**; although certainly they both mean the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macmillan Dictionary states the difference as

'About', adverb

- used for stating who or what you are discussing, etc.

'Concerning', preposition,
FORMAL

- about a particular subject

You are right, that option (1) is more formal than option (2).